# How to set up VisPy?

Tags: python

I am attempting to set up VisPy using Python 2.7.6. After installing PyQt4 and SIP for a 64 bit machine, I've executed the configuration.py script from the SIP archive, it appears to have run correctly, however when running sample scripts from the VisPy gallery, I am consistently receiving no backend errors. I can post these errors a bit later if needed.  Does anybody have a straightforward way to set up this environment on a windows 64 bit machine using python 2.7.6?

Errors Received:

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\python.exe C:/pyvis/frequency.py
INFO: Could not import backend "PyQt4":
DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
INFO: Could not import backend "PyQt5":
No module named PyQt5
INFO: Could not import backend "PySide":
No module named PySide
INFO: Could not import backend "Pyglet":
No module named pyglet
INFO: Could not import backend "Glfw":
GLFW library not found
INFO: Could not import backend "SDL2":
No module named sdl2
INFO: Could not import backend "wx":
No module named wx
INFO: Could not import backend "EGL":
EGL library not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pyvis/frequency.py", line 101, in <module>
    c = Canvas()
  File "C:/pyvis/frequency.py", line 60, in __init__
    app.Canvas.__init__(self, size=(800, 600), keys='interactive')
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\vispy\app\canvas.py", line 167, in __init__
    self._app = use_app(call_reuse=False)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\vispy\app\_default_app.py", line 46, in use_app
    default_app = Application(backend_name)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\vispy\app\application.py", line 49, in __init__
    self._use(backend_name)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\vispy\app\application.py", line 224, in _use
    'PyQt' % [b[0] for b in CORE_BACKENDS])
RuntimeError: Could not import any of the backends. You need to install any of ['PyQt4', 'PyQt5', 'PySide', 'Pyglet', 'Glfw', 'SDL2', 'wx', 'EGL']. We recommend PyQt

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: "I can post these errors a bit later if needed." Why not post them straightaway?

Comment: I was away from my machine.

Comment: "DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application." It would appear the Python executable you are using is a 32 bit executable; could you check?